# How to GROUP BY Month-Year using BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to count the number of bus trips (with start and destinations) on monthly basis (for several years) using `TIMESTAMP` column/field.  I can do this on MONTH basis (`TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(start_date, MONTH)`) but I would like to do this for MONTH-YEAR basis. Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: `TIMESTAMP_TRUNC()` does truncate to the year *and* month. What don't you like about your current query?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use Standard SQL:

```
SELECT 
  FORMAT_DATE('%b-%Y', created_date) mon_year, 
  COUNT(1) AS `count`
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY mon_year
ORDER BY PARSE_DATE('%b-%Y', mon_year)
```

if you are using timestamp you have to cast it to `date`

```sql
SELECT
  FORMAT_DATE('%b-%Y', DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())) mon_year
```

will produce:

```
Sep-2020
```

As per your example from comments. You can't use `count` in `where` clause. If you want to have a filter on aggregation you have to use `having` [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#having_clause).

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(start_date, MONTH) AS year_month,
       start_station_name,
       end_station_name,
       count(start_station_name) AS count_start,
FROM bigquery-PUBLIC-data.san_francisco.bikeshare_trips
WHERE start_station_name <> end_station_name
GROUP BY year_month,
         start_station_name,
         end_station_name
HAVING count(start_station_name) > 10
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Hi, FORMAT_DATE works and mon_year is generated.  However, I still have a problem with the query.  The query is expected to produce the count of start_station_name and the start_station_name (counted every month-year).   I am using below query.  Thanks   SELECT  
   FORMAT_DATE('%b-%Y', DATE(start_date)) as mon_year, COUNT(start_station_name), start_station_name  
FROM `bigquery-public-data.san_francisco.bikeshare_trips`   
GROUP BY mon_year   
ORDER BY PARSE_DATE('%b-%Y', mon_year)    
LIMIT 20

Comment: You should include start_station_name in group by

Comment: Thanks! It works and now I understood how GROUP BY works.

Comment: Now, I got stuck with WHERE condition.    Wondering if WHERE clause only works with data columns or also works with COUNT(*) values?    Thanks in advance SELECT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(start_date, MONTH) as year_month, count(start_station_name) as count_start, start_station_name, end_station_name
FROM `bigquery-public-data.san_francisco.bikeshare_trips` 
WHERE start_station_name <> end_station_name AND count_start > 10
GROUP BY year_month, start_station_name, end_station_name
LIMIT 50

Comment: You can use where to filter out end stations but for count you have to use having (aggregations won’t work with where)

Comment: I've edited my answer, if that solves your problem please mark it as accepted and close the topic. It's better to keep question separated, so for any new issues please create new questions to keep things organized

Answer (score 1):

Your code should do what you want:

```
select timestamp_trunc(start_date, month) as yyyymmm, count(*)
from t
group by yyyymm;
```

This includes both the *year* and *month*, so Jan 2020 is different from Jan 2019.

If you wanted just by month of the year, then use `extract()`:

```
select extract(month from start_date) as mon, count(*)
from t
group by mon;
```

This would treat Jan 2020 as the same as Jan 2019.